# цикл по десятым долям числа

Tags: perl

Обычно `print foreach 1 .. 5`  напечатает `12345`.

Как сделать так, чтобы был цикл по *десятым долям*, скажем с шагом `0.2` ?

Или модуль какой есть?

Спасибо!

Comment: используйте обычный трехоперандный, C-style цикл `for(my $i=1; $i<10; $i+=0.2)`

Comment: @Mike, будет погрешность из-за кучи сложений.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо. не подумал. значит целочисленные операции и деление в последний момент наиболее точный вариант.

Comment: @Mike ага. Ну или счётчик и умножение в более общем случае.

Answer (score 5):

Чем не угодил цикл `for`?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i+= 0.2)
```

Comment: о, спасибо, не знал!

Comment: @vilfred может вы не знаете, нужно ставить галочку у правильных ответов, чтобы авторы получили карму(вы тоже)

Comment: `<= 5` - а вот если точно 5 не получится?

Comment: @Qwertiy Тут нужно узнавать у автора как он к этому отнесется. Вы предлагаете нечто такое `$i < 5 + 0.2 / 2`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, лучше делать заданное число итераций и считать значение. Или вообще как в соседнем ответе. Кстати, 4.800000000000002 последнее значение получается у тебя.

Answer (score 2):

```
    foreach $i (10..50)

     {

            print $i/5;

      }
```

Пусть надо пройти от а до b с шагом с. Тогда

```
foreach $i (a/c..b/c)

     {

            print $i*c;

      }
```

В вашем примере с=0.2. А лучше, действительно, использовать for.

Comment: я не это имел ввиду. ваше напечатает perl -e 'print $_/5  foreach 1 .. 5'
0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1 а мне надо чтобы выводилось 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2.0 2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8 .... 4.6 4.8 5

Comment: А что имел в виду?

Comment: т.е. мне надо пройти циклом не от одного до 10, а от одного до 100 с шагом 0.2 или с шагом 2/3 или с шагом 5/7 например, или с шагом например 1/17 . лучше бы модуль который такой цикл раелизует

Comment: Шаг 1/17 - Значит умножать на 17. В модуле функции, а не новый синтаксис цикла.

Comment: спасибо большое!!!