# Задачка с e-olymp

Tags: haskell

```
import Text.Printf

funnc :: Float -> Float -> Float -> IO()
funnc a b h = do 
    printf "%.3f %.3f\n" (a::Float) (3*sin a::Float)
    if a < b
        then funnc (a+h) b h
    else return ()

main = do 
    [aa,bb,hh] <- (map read . words) `fmap` getLine
    funnc aa bb hh
```

Напишите программу, которая выводит на экран таблицу значений функции y = 3 · sin(x) на промежутке от a до b включительно с шагом h. Входные данные

В одной строке через пробел заданы три вещественных числа a, b и h. Выходные данные

В каждой строке выведите по два числа x и y соответственно, по возрастанию x с тремя десятичными знаками.

Проходит 6/10 тестов, помогите пожалуйста найти, в чём проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как раз рядом вопрос в тему: [цикл по десятым долям числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/732697/178988)

Беру твой код и даю input

```
1 5 0.2
```

Получаю результат https://ideone.com/kBWQMN

```
1.000 2.524
1.200 2.796
1.400 2.956
1.600 2.999
1.800 2.922
2.000 2.728
2.200 2.425
2.400 2.026
2.600 1.547
2.800 1.005
3.000 0.423
3.200 -0.175
3.400 -0.767
3.600 -1.328
3.800 -1.836
4.000 -2.270
4.200 -2.615
4.400 -2.855
4.600 -2.981
4.800 -2.988
5.000 -2.877
5.200 -2.650
```

Что тут делает строчка с 5.2?

PS: На Хаскеле не программирую.

Answer (score 0):

Это стандартная ошибка при вычислениях с плавающей точкой.
Проверка условия 4.8+0.2 < 5.0, дало истину, так как 0.2 в двоичной арифметике - бесконечная периодическая дробь. "Хвост" отбросили и неравенство стало истинным. Соответственно цикл еще раз сработал.
При выводе 4.99999... округлилось до 5.000.